# Make Django first search message files (.mo) for current application

Tags: django, translation

Django searches for messages files (.mo) in the order that is documented here: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations

Is it possible to have Django first search for messages files in the locale directory for the app that is currently being used?

I recently discoverd a bug in a project, that was caused by two apps having the same message-id but different translation. All the apps have their own locale directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not how django works for various reasons:

1. A single phrase should have a single translation. Django aside, this is a matter of gettext as well (the engine used for translation messages). Besides, it sounds normal to expect from a system to translate a single phrase with consistency in all pages. It still is the same phrase in the original language after all.
2. What would 'current application' mean? Is current application the one generating the current view? The translation itself might be coming from a module of another application. How to decide which of these two applications is appropriate? Translations can also be lazy which adds additional complexity to such decisions.

I suggest that you reorder your applications in `INSTALLED_APPS` to match the translation you prefer, or define a new translation messages path using the `LOCALE_PATHS` setting to provide a translation of your own.

**Note:** Technically, it is possible to override the default behavior in django.utils.translation.trans_real by providing a custom implementation of this module to change the behavior as you wish (it is the `translation()` method in this module that implements the selection algorithm). Then you should also override the `Trans` class originally defined in `django.utils.translation.__init__` module to return your custom trans_real module (name this new class `MyCustomTrans` for example) and explicitly set it as the translation class somewhere in your project's init module, so that it loads early in the code:

```
from django.utils import translation
translation._trans = MyCustomTrans()
```

Now your custom algorithm would be used instead, but this would require a lot of work and in my opinion does not worth the hassle.